# Keydown check on 2 forms with same name

Tags: jquery

Hi i have a code when there are new messages it wil generate `<form id=replyForm>` below all messages.
Now i want to make it possible to send data pressing ENTER key now it works for the first `form` but it ignores the second third etc.etc. 
What i'm doing wrong can someone help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/a9g1a7o0/

```
<form id=replyForm>
    <textarea id=reply></textarea>
</form>
<form id=replyForm>
    <textarea id=reply></textarea>
</form>

var replyForm = $('#replyForm');
var replyVal = $('#reply');

replyForm.on('keydown', function(evt) {
    var key = (evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : evt.which);
    if (key === 13) {
        if (replyVal.val()) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'reply.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: replyForm.serialize() + '&reply=',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            replyVal.val("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I didnt understand what you want to do?

Comment: Try the JsFiddle, the function works if you enter inside the first textarea on the second textarea it doenst work.

Comment: Do NOT make link-only posts. Links will break some day rendering the post useless. Embedd the most important content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use "id". usually you declare "id" once in a document. use the "class" tag

try this:http://jsfiddle.net/a9g1a7o0/2/

```
var replyForm = $('.replyForm');

replyForm.on('keydown', function(evt) {

    var key = (evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : evt.which);

    // get the reply from selected form
    replyField = $(this).find("textarea");
    replyVal = replyField.val();

    if (key === 13) {
        // prevent enter, line down
        evt.preventDefault();

        // test, append reply val to document
        // delete this line
        $('body').append(replyVal + '<br>');

        if (replyVal) {
            // do ajax stuff
            $.ajax({
                url: 'reply.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: replyForm.serialize() + '&reply=',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            // clear field
            replyField.val('');
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks didnt know about the ID issue, do you also know how to prevent the jump one paragraf down after enter ?

Comment: id is unique because its an identifier for your browser site.com/index.html#yourid directs your browser to the line the id is specified...  

add a evt.preventDefault() to the js code, fiddle link below: 
http://jsfiddle.net/a9g1a7o0/4/

Comment: please post your original code to your initial post, so others can see your problem if the fiddles are deleted... like Silicomancer proposed

Comment: Done, so i can't also use name tag inside the textarea with same name like `<textarea class=reply name=reply-message>` because this will multiply based on messages ?

Comment: dont get that. if you are on the first field and press enter the first fields content is transmitted via ajax, same on the second field.. change the "data: refplyForm..." to data: {reply: replyVal} ... your $ajax wont work

Answer (score 0):

*id*'s in HTML must be unique within a document, two different elements can't have the same `id`.

You must select them through some other mean, e.g. using the `class` attribute:

HTML

```
<form class="replyForm">
    <textarea class="reply"></textarea>
</form>
<form class="replyForm">
    <textarea class="reply"></textarea>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
var replyForm = $('.replyForm');
var replyVal = $('.reply');
```